# How to understand a basic opener in ASP.Net, page tag?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was wondering if anyone could explain this to me:

```
<%@ Page Title="Log In" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="greetwithus.Account.Login" %>
```

This is when I create a simple .net web application in visual studio.  I obviously understand the title part, language part, but not the rest.  I was wondering if someone could explain this line of code to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as the [`@Page` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx), once you know they're called directives, you can find help pretty easily :)

MSDN has a full description of every atribute here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx

For your example (see the msdn link for even more detailed descriptions):

> - **MasterPageFile** - Sets the path to the master page for the content page or nested master page. Supports relative and absolute paths. For more information, see the [MasterPageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.masterpagefile.aspx) property.
> - **AutoEventWireup** - Indicates whether the page's events are autowired. true if event autowiring is enabled; otherwise, false. The default is true. For more information, see [ASP.NET Web Server Control Event Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx).
> - **CodeBehind** - Specifies the name of the compiled file that contains the class associated with the page. This attribute is not used at run time.
> - **Inherits** - Defines a code-behind class for the page to inherit. This can be any class derived from the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class. This attribute is used with the CodeFile attribute, which contains the path to the source file for the code-behind class. The Inherits attribute is case-sensitive when using C# as the page language, and case-insensitive when using Visual Basic as the page language.

If you're curious, [there are other directives as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

This is known as a **Page Directive**. You can read more about it on the [MSDN topic here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx).